# Intel XDK splash screen still shows after calling hideSplashScreen();

Tags: splash-screen, intel-xdk

I used the following function call to hide the splash screen but when I build the app, it is still showing up. I have deselected the SplashScreen Cordova plugin. Are there any other steps I am missing? Thanks!

```
<script>               
    function onDeviceReady(){
        intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();   
    }        
    document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready", onDeviceReady, false);        
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the appropriate plugin selected for your app. Don't use the Intel XDK version of this function (base plugin), it has been deprecated. Use the Cordova version (splash screen plugin), instead.

This function will work with either the Cordova or the XDK function:

```
app.hideSplashScreen = function() {
    "use strict" ;

    // see https://github.com/01org/appframework/blob/master/documentation/detail/%24.ui.launch.md
    // Do the following if you disabled App Framework autolaunch (in index.html, for example)
    // $.ui.launch() ;

    if( navigator.splashscreen && navigator.splashscreen.hide ) {   // Cordova API detected
        navigator.splashscreen.hide() ;
    }
    if( window.intel && intel.xdk && intel.xdk.device ) {           // Intel XDK device API detected, but...
        if( intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen )                     // ...hideSplashScreen() is inside the base plugin
            intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen() ;
    }
} ;
```

It is derived from a similarly named function inside the `init-app.js` file in this XDK template > https://github.com/gomobile/template-blank-cordova-project